# Cannot detect background color from PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, background

I'm a web developer who has recently been given a desing in a PSD file. I previously worked with *Zeplin*. I'm using a trial version of *Avocode* to extract information from this PSD file. Everything is fine except for one thing.

I cannot find what is the background color (the background color of the component that is marked as *Background layer*). It looks like dark blue but in *Avocode* it does not show *background-color* property as for all other components. The properties of this background component are just *width*, *height*, and *opacity 100%*.

I also tried to export this component. If I export as SVG it shows me transparent-marking squares, if I export as PNG it shows me dark-blue.

Does someone know what is going on here, is background somehow transparent or what?

If really necessary I'll try to share the actual PSD file.

[image]

Comment: Could be that Avocode can't do it's thing on a locked layer? Try unlocking the background layer.

Comment: Well, till you figure things out, let me tell you that the blue color you are seeing is #3b4263

Answer (score 1):

No experience with Zeplin or Avocode, but.....

**Does the PSD file have a base layer *actually* named *"Background"*?**

If the answer is "no" then there is no "background layer".

You can choose the base layer and then select `Layer > New > Background from Layer` to convert it to an *actual* background layer in Photoshop.

Note this will **remove all transparency** on that layer and flatten it using your set background color as a base to fill in transparent areas.

Comment: Yes. It has the Background layer. I've updated my answer.